# Why is this '$(...).trigger("click")' not working inside this function (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

The following function opens a popup window when I click a link:

```
function popupPlace(dict) {
    $popup = $('div#dish-popup');
    $popup.render(dict,window.dishPopupTemplate);
    if(typeof(dict.dish) === 'undefined') {
        $popup.addClass('place-only');
    } else {
        $popup.removeClass('place-only');
    }

    var $place = $('div#dish-popup div.place');
    var place_id = dict.place._id;
    if(liked[place_id]) {
        $place.addClass('liked');
    } else {
        $place.removeClass('liked');
    }
    if(dict.place.likes) {
        $place.addClass('has-likes');
    } else {
        $place.addClass('zero-likes');
    }


    var tokens = window.currentSearchTermTokens;
    var tokenRegex = tokens && new RegExp($.map(tokens, RegExp.escape).join('|'), 'gi');
    $.each(dict.place.products, function(n, product) {
        $product = $('#menu-item-'+product.id);
        if(liked[place_id+'/'+product.id]) {
            $product.addClass('liked');
        }
        if(tokens && matchesDish(product, tokens)) {
            $product.addClass('matched');
            $product.highlight(tokenRegex);
        } else {
            $product.removeClass('matched');
            $product.removeHighlight();
        }
        if(product.likes) {
            $product.addClass('has-likes');
        } else {
            $product.addClass('zero-likes');
        }
    });

    $('#overlay').show();
    $('#dish-popup-container').show();

    // Scroll to matched dish
    $("a#scrolll").attr("href", "#" + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    $("a#scrolll").trigger("click");

    // Hide dish results on mobile devices to prevent having a blank space at the bottom of the site
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 640px)')) {
        $('ol.results').hide();
    }

    $(".close-dish-popup").click(function() {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        $("#dish-popup-container").hide();
        $('ol.results').show();
        changeState({}, ['dish', 'place', 'serp']);
    });

    showPopupMap(dict.place, "dish-popup-map");
}
```

At the end you can see the following:

```
    $("a#scrolll").trigger("click");
```

Everything works but that link is not being triggered as soon as the popup shows up:

```
    $('#dish-popup-container').show();
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: What happens if you replace `.trigger("click")` with `.click()`?

Comment: Could you possibly put this up in a http://jsfiddle.net/ example so we can see it in action?

Comment: this works:     `$("#scrolll").click(function() {
  $("a#scrolll").attr("href", "#" + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
    });` inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling the <strike>`$("a#scrolll").trigger("click");` before assigning</strike>`$('#dish-popup-container').show();` before assigning the click event to the close button.
just put the `$(".close-dish-popup").click();` out side of the function or top of the function(before calling it)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see that function being called in the code.

Comment: `$(".close-dish-popup").click();` just  closes the popup menu I don't think it has something t do with the `#scrolll` link.

Comment: when you show the popup the click event is not assigned. put the click event outside or before `$('#dish-popup-container').show();`

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal but the click event is not inside `$('#dish-popup-container').show();` but below (I tried putting it before but it didn't help).

Comment: click event is not inside the show event, that's true. but when you show the popup close event is not assigned to the close button.

Answer (score 1):

put

```
$(".close-dish-popup").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#dish-popup-container").hide();
    $('ol.results').show();
    changeState({}, ['dish', 'place', 'serp']);
});
```

in $(document).ready out side of

```
function popupPlace(dict) {
```

you are trying to call it but it is not initialized the time you are calling it

Comment: `$(".close-dish-popup").click(function() {
...` is working fine what is not working is `$("a#scrolll").trigger("click");`

Comment: when you trigger the click function it calls the click function . it is like you are calling a method . think you call a method test(). to call a method test you have to initialize your test() metod . before you call it , in jquery we normally put user defined functions out side document.ready , and jquery functions like click in the document.ready to initiaze when the DOM loading , in this case you are trying to access a function ,it is not initialized yet . if you defined click in your $(document).ready it will be available when you call it